# creating triangle with given string using 2 for loops

Tags: java, for-loop

Given a string such as hello, it should output:

```
h
he
hel
hell
hello
hell
hel
he
h
```

so far I have:

```
 public static String Triangle(String str) {
    int length =str.length();
    for (int i=0; i<=length;i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            System.out.print(str.substring(0, i));
        }
    }
    for (int i=0; i<=length;i--) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            System.out.print(str.substring(0, i));
        }
    return str;
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is your problem? What does your current code output?

Comment: @GBlodgett it gives me a compilation error of "This method must return a result of type String"

Comment: Why should your method return anything?

Comment: Move the return outside of the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two mistakes in your code

1. No need of nested loops in both the for loop
2. Return statement should be last fi you prefer (but you are not using it anywhere so you can remove it)

---

```
public static void triangle(String str) {
    int length =str.length();
    for (int i=0; i<length;i++) {
         System.out.println(str.substring(0, i));
    }
    for (int i=length; i>0;i--) {
        System.out.println(str.substring(0, i));

    }
    //return str;  no need of this
}
```

**Output**

```
h
he
hel
hell
hello
hell
hel
he
h
```

**coding standards** Method name should start with lowercase

Comment: how should I write it if using return statement since I'm writing small problems under one main?

Comment: updated add it at last line in method @user10947891but you should have method return type as `String`